# implement abstract byref method in c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, inheritance, byref

I have an abstract class method:

```
Public Class Base_BLL
{
    Public Overridable Function Persist(ByRef x As Base_BO) As Base_BO
    {
    }
}

Public CLass ActualBLL Inherits Base_BLL
{
}

public Class Main_BO Inherits Base_BO
{
}
```

I am reusing old vb code, and have a C# presenter class which is trying to persist the Main_BO class using the ActualBLL method.  But I can't get it to compile:

```
ActualBLL bll = new ActualBLL()
Main_BO bo = new Main_BO()
bo.ID="3"
bo = bll.Persist(ref bo)
```

Compiler doesn't like it one bit.  However, in VB the following line compiles fine:

```
bo = bll.Persist(bo);
```

I'm at a bit of a loss here...

Comment: What does the compiler tell you (i.e., what error does it give you)?

Comment: So you have a library written in vb.net that you are referencing and using in a c# project? and what is the error the compiler is spitting out.

Comment: It's saying "the best overloaded method match for Base_BLL.Persist(ref Base_BO) has some invalid arguments."

Comment: Just an off the cuff guess, but could it be that the C# compiler doesn't like you passing in a Main_BO object when it's expecting a Base_BO object?  Yes, I see that in your code Main_BO inherits Base_BO, but C# tends to be a little more strict than VB, especially if you don't set Option Explicit (I think) on.

Comment: BTW, what does `Persist` take a `ref Base_BO` reference *and* return a `Base_BO` for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C# compiler is stricter, it does not insert these casts for you.

```
Main_BO bo = new Main_BO() ;
// ...
Base_BO br = bo ;
bo = (Main_BO) bll.Persist (ref br) ;
```

Comment: Thanks!  This cracked it. The vb was throwing me off I think!

Comment: Just out of curiousity, would Option Strict prevent this kind of implicit casting in VB.NET?

Comment: Yes - Option Strict On would require you to explicitly cast these cases.